# Specific time lapses on each line of?

Tags: python, time, timing

So I made a script, and I need it to spend a set amount of time on a certain line. Does anyone know what moduel to look into? or just help me out on what to do?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import time
import sys

def delay_print(s):
    for c in s:
        sys.stdout.write( '%s' % c )
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.0001)

delay_print(" Welcome to the terminal. Please hit enter to continue. ")
raw_input(">")
delay_print(" Loading data Please wait")
delay_print("[============================]") time.sleep(0.01)
```

But where it says "time.sleep(0.01)" in the last line, I want it to spend a different amount on each line if specified.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just asking how to add another parameter to a function? I'll give you that, plus a few bonuses.

---

```
def delay_print(s, delay=0.0001):
    for c in s:
        sys.stdout.write( '%s' % c )
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(delay)
```

Notice the default value of `0.0001`, so you don't have to pass something on every line, just the ones that aren't `0.0001`.

---

```
delay_print(" Welcome to the terminal. Please hit enter to continue. ")
raw_input(">")
delay_print(" Loading data Please wait")
delay_print("[============================]", delay=0.01)
```

Notice that on the last line, I passed `delay` as a keyword argument. The way it's defined, you can also call it with a positional argument:

```
delay_print("[============================]", 0.01)
```

I think the keyword argument adds clarity here, but if you disagree, well, that's why they both work. :)